# Comparing two list of dictionaries to find common values of a particular field

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionary like this

```
ref = [{"url":"https://example1.com","category":"sports"},
       {"url":"https://example2.com","category":"movie"},
       {"url":"https://example3.com","category":"sports"},
       {"url":"https://example4.com","category":"sports"}]
```

and another list of dictionary

```
ref = [{"url":"https://example1.com","org":"sports"},
       {"url":"https://example5.com","org":"movie"},
       {"url":"https://example2.com","org":"sports"},
       {"url":"https://examplex.com","org":"movie"},
       {"url":"https://example3.com","org":"sports"}]
```

and I want list of dictionary which have common url value

```
["https://example1.com","https://example2.com", "https://example3.com"]
```

I am trying like this

```
[i for i in new["url"] if i in ref["url"]]
```

Comment: you can put all the urls inside a single list, remove all the urls that appear only one time and then remove duplicate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this uses set comprehensions and is fairly concise:

```
ref1 = [{"url":"https://example1.com","category":"sports"},
       {"url":"https://example2.com","category":"movie"},
       {"url":"https://example3.com","category":"sports"},
       {"url":"https://example4.com","category":"sports"}]


ref2 = [{"url":"https://example1.com","org":"sports"},
       {"url":"https://example5.com","org":"movie"},
       {"url":"https://example2.com","org":"sports"},
       {"url":"https://examplex.com","org":"movie"},
       {"url":"https://example3.com","org":"sports"}]

ref3 = list({d['url'] for d in ref1} & {d['url'] for d in ref2})

print(ref3)
```

> ['https://example1.com', 'https://example2.com','https://example3.com']

Sets are not ordered, so the fact that they come out in numerical order is only by virtue of the ordering of your example list, but you could always just sort the final list in whatever order you would like.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution

```
ref = [{"url":"https://example1.com","category":"sports"},
       {"url":"https://example2.com","category":"movie"},
       {"url":"https://example3.com","category":"sports"},
       {"url":"https://example4.com","category":"sports"}]

ref2 = [{"url":"https://example1.com","org":"sports"},
       {"url":"https://example5.com","org":"movie"},
       {"url":"https://example2.com","org":"sports"},
       {"url":"https://examplex.com","org":"movie"},
       {"url":"https://example3.com","org":"sports"}]

mylist = []
for x in range(0, len(ref)):
  mylist.append(ref[x]['url'])

for x in range(0, len(ref2)):
  mylist.append(ref2[x]['url'])

newlist = set([x for x in mylist if mylist.count(x) > 1])
print(newlist)
```

Basically it first merges the elements of the dictionary you need into a single list and the keep only the items that occure more than one time with `set`

Answer (score 1):

```
url_list = list()    
for url in ref:
        for url2 in ref2:
            if url['url'] == url2['url']:
                url_list.append(url['url'])
```